# I cannot change the fragment by clicking on tab using TabHost in android

Tags: java, android-fragments, setter

I have created an activity with three fragment and setting view pager to it..... View pager is working properly, but tabs not working. When selecting tab it will load values in fragment class but not displaying... below is the code for ontabchange()

```
TabHost.OnTabChangeListener tabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                    mFManager =   getSupportFragmentManager();
                    AndroidFragment androidFragment = (AndroidFragment) mFManager.findFragmentByTag("android");
                    AppleFragment appleFragment = (AppleFragment) mFManager.findFragmentByTag("apple");
                    MicrosoftFragment microsoftFragment = (MicrosoftFragment) mFManager.findFragmentByTag("microsoft");
                    mFTransaction = mFManager.beginTransaction();

                    if(androidFragment!=null)
                    {
                        mFTransaction.detach(androidFragment);
                    }

                    if(appleFragment!=null)
                    {
                        mFTransaction.detach(appleFragment);
                    }
                    if(microsoftFragment!=null)
                    {
                        mFTransaction.detach(microsoftFragment);
                    }

                    if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("android"))
                    {

                        if(androidFragment==null)
                        {
                            mFTransaction.add(R.id.tab1,new AndroidFragment(), "android");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mFTransaction.attach(androidFragment);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("apple"))
                    {
                        if(appleFragment==null)
                        {
                            mFTransaction.add(R.id.tab1,new AppleFragment(), "apple");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mFTransaction.attach(appleFragment);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(tabId.equalsIgnoreCase("microsoft"))
                    {
                        if(microsoftFragment==null)
                        {
                            mFTransaction.add(R.id.tab1,new MicrosoftFragment(), "microsoft");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mFTransaction.attach(microsoftFragment);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(androidFragment==null)
                        {
                            mFTransaction.add(R.id.tab1,new AndroidFragment(), "android");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mFTransaction.attach(androidFragment);
                        }
                    }
                    mFTransaction.commit();
                }
            };

            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(tabChangeListener);
            TabHost.TabSpec tSpecAndroid = mTabHost.newTabSpec("android");
            tSpecAndroid.setIndicator("Android",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android));
            tSpecAndroid.setContent(new FragmentControl(getBaseContext()));
            mTabHost.addTab(tSpecAndroid);

            TabHost.TabSpec tSpecApple = mTabHost.newTabSpec("apple");
            tSpecApple.setIndicator("Apple",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.apple));
            tSpecApple.setContent(new FragmentControl(getBaseContext()));
            mTabHost.addTab(tSpecApple);

            TabHost.TabSpec tSpecMicrosoft = mTabHost.newTabSpec("microsoft");
            tSpecMicrosoft.setIndicator("microsoft",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.microsoft));
            tSpecMicrosoft.setContent(new FragmentControl(getBaseContext()));
            mTabHost.addTab(tSpecMicrosoft);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Please help to solve.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle found answer.......
want to add view pager and tab to separate list with fragment.... answer is
separate class

```
  public class TabInformation 
{
public String tag;
private Class<?> clss;
private Bundle args;
private Fragment fragment;

TabInformation(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) 
{
    this.tag = tag;
    this.clss = clazz;
    this.args = args;
}
```

}

Tab Initialization in MainActivity

```
 private void TabInitialize(Bundle args) 
 {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInformation tabInfo = null;
    MainActivity.AddTab(this,mTabHost, mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("Andorid"), ( tabInfo = new TabInformation("Tab1", AndroidFragment.class, args)));
    mTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, mTabHost, mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("Apple"), ( tabInfo = new TabInformation("Tab2", AppleFragment.class, args)));
    mTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, mTabHost, mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("Microsoft"), ( tabInfo = new TabInformation("Tab3", MicrosoftFragment.class, args)));
    mTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    setSelectedTabColor();
 }
```

View Pager Initialization in MainActivity

```
 private void ViewPagerInitialize()
 {
     List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AndroidFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, AppleFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MicrosoftFragment.class.getName()));
        mPageradapter  = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPageradapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
 }    

 private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInformation tabInfo) 
 {
        tabSpec.setContent(new FragmentControl(activity));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
  }
```